# Why List<float>.Sum() and manual sum of numbers gives different result in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, sum, shared-libraries

in C# I have following code:

```
public static float sum(List<float> array)
    {
        float result = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            result += array[i];

        float lSum = array.Sum();

        return result;
    }
```

Why result of those two 'different' approaches differs?

For an array of length *911380* elements **result**=*620246* and **lSum**=*620235.8*

What is internal implementation of List.Sum and which answer is correct? Is it problem of C# language/library or does it depends on implementation of **+** in Windows?

We do research about human brain and heart activity and we need correct results, so I appreciate any kind of help! Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: FWIW that's an error of 1.1x10^-5 per element. Not sure you're gonna get much better precision since `float` is only accurate down to 6 or 7 digits. You might get better results with `double`. Doesn't answer the question of why the two answers are different though.

Comment: Is your actual code using an array or a List? I'm wondering because `.Length` applies to an array whereas for a List it should be `.Count`

Comment: Thank you @Ciara for noticing that. There should be `.Count` as write. My original code is: `sum(List<float> array, int from, int to) ... for (int i = from; i < to; i++)` I made in-place modification and I made mistake ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Sum` extension method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,c69f184d56badef0) uses a `double` to accumulate the result and only casts to `float` to return it, so it's more precise than using `float`:

```
public static float Sum(this IEnumerable<float> source) 
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    double sum = 0;
    foreach (float v in source) sum += v;
    return (float)sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank You @jakub you are right, it's better to use `double` to accumulate result and the retype to get correct result. It's accumulation of errors as @lc has mentioned in his comment. When I did `double` accumulation with retyping `result` the result was the same :)